# Checkbutton checks itself regardless of state

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a checkbutton in my tkinter window that is otherwise working fine, but it starts as greyed out and checked no matter what I do. I have to click it once to remove the grey, then again to uncheck it. I have no idea why it's doing this, other than that it only happens when using StringVar, as opposed to IntVar for example. I just want it to start unchecked like any other regular checkbox would do. Here's my code:

```
 self.symptom1Var = StringVar()
 self.symptomCheck1 = Checkbutton(self, text="Symptom", variable = self.symptom1Var)
 self.symptomCheck1.grid(row=2, column=0)
```

Comment: What is the _initial_ value of `symptom1Var`?

Comment: Use the deselect() or select() function to modify the default state, depending on how you want to start them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem is that you're not giving the checkbutton a default value so it starts out in an indeterminate state.

The initial value of a `StringVar` is an empty string, the default "on" value of a checkbutton is `1` and the default "off" value of a checkbutton is `0`. Since you haven't set it to be either `1` or `0`, it's in the indeterminate state (neither checked nor unchecked).

The solution is to make sure it's set to either the checked or unchecked state by setting the associated variable:

```
self.symptom1Var.set(1)
```